# gpo proxy server settinngs for all applications

Tags: networking, proxy, group-policy, windows-server-2003-r2

i am trying to set all internet connections of all network PCs via proxy server that is installed on windows server 2003
i have editted proxy setting from gpo, but it only worked for internet browsers, is there way to force all applications to use that proxy (applications like chatting apps, IDM, torrent and others)

note: i am using ccproxy as a proxy server

Comment: Implementation of a GPO method for controlling settings is completely dependant on the application supporting configuration via the Windows registry. If the settings are stored in a file you would need another method like script to make the changes. Normally you would block them at a firewall to force them through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Internet Explorer's proxy settings affect Internet Explorer only. If you want all internet traffic to go through the proxy server then set the proxy server as the default gateway for all of the computers. You can do this easily and automatically with DHCP but if you use static ip addresses then you'll have to do it manually at each computer.